# How can I mock static methods in Java 1.4?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, java1.4

I'm using JUnit with Mockito. [PowerMock](http://powermock.org/) can mock static methods but it doesn't seem to be possible to use it with Java 1.4, specially since it needs annotations.

Is there any other alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: One alternative that someone (if not you) need to consider is upgrading your target Java platform.  Java 1.5 / 5.0 came out in 2004.

Comment: We are migrating, but in the meantime we're stuck with 1.4.

Comment: If you are migrating, wait until you have migrated.  Use a simply but ugly approach until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Shameless self promotion here)
There is a project [PowerMock-Legacy](http://code.google.com/p/powermock-legacy/) that lets you use PowerMock in Java 1.4. It is a bit verbose, and not all functionality is supported, but may worth a try.

Comment: Looks good. Even though I'd like to not need to mock static methods, that's probably the best answer to the given question.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer minimizing my use of mocks.  If the static method is in your code, I'd modify it to make it more unit test friendly.  Maybe it shouldn't be static.  Or if it has to be, maybe you could use a setup method that determines how the static method behaves.

If the static method is not in your code, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I personally favor the use of mocks so to be able to make true unit tests. I agree it shouldn't be static, but unfortunately I can't change it for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/) and double check if you can refactor the code (or is it legacy code?). Mockito says about mocking static Methods

> Mockito prefers object orientation and dependency injection over static, procedural code that is hard to understand & change. ([Source](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ))

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203027/how-can-i-easily-mock-out-a-static-method-in-java-junit4) related post especially Jon's answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it is legacy code I can't change for the moment. But I agree, the long term goal is to not use static methods at all.