# Trying to run junit test on service level of Spring WebFlow Project. Assume$AssumptionViolatedException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-webflow

I am trying to run my first test with junit on a Spring Web Flow Project from within Eclipse and also from the console with mvn test and but give me the same error.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assume$AssumptionViolatedException

Here is my java code:

```
package org.uftwf.memberinquiry.text;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.uftwf.memberinquiry.model.MemberInquiryInformation;
import org.uftwf.memberinquiry.model.MemberRequest;
import org.uftwf.memberinquiry.service.MemberInquiryService;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:root-config.xml")
public class TestApp {

    @Autowired
    private MemberInquiryService service;

    @Test
    public void testgetMemeberRequestInformation() {

        MemberRequest inMemberRequest = new MemberRequest();

        MemberInquiryInformation testInfo = service.getMemeberRequestInformation(inMemberRequest);

        inMemberRequest.setRequestor("cpilling04@aol.com.dev");


        Assert.assertEquals(testInfo.getFirst_Name(), "Christine");
        Assert.assertEquals(testInfo.getLast_Name(), "Pillings");
    }

}
```

and here is my pox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.uftwf.memberinquiry</groupId>
    <artifactId>MemberInquiry</artifactId>
    <name>Member Inquiry</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>jsmith</id>
            <name>Johnathan Smith</name>
            <email>johnatham.smith@uftwf.org</email>
            <roles>
                <role>Architect</role>
            </roles>
            <organization>uftwf.org</organization>
            <timezone>-5</timezone>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.5</java-version>
        <springframework-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</springframework-version>
        <springwebflow-version>2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</springwebflow-version>
        <springsecurity-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</springsecurity-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <!-- will come with all needed Spring dependencies such as spring-core 
                and spring-beans -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>${springwebflow-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF-303 Dependency Injection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Sun Mojarra JSF 2 runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSR 303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
            ** HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES ** ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For Hibernate Validator -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For Sun Mojarra JSF 2 implementation -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For PrimeFaces JSF component library -->

    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mode>both</mode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <finalName>MemberInquiry</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

and for the best part my error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assume$AssumptionViolatedException
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(SpringMethodRoadie.java:281)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$2.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:207)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:234)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:204)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assume$AssumptionViolatedException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to upgrade my version of spring-test and junit both to the most updated versions and bang everything is working great!

Answer (score 8):

This is a shot in the dark - but I found [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?60230-spring-test-breaks-in-Junit-4-5) on spring's forum. 
It is consistent with your configuration - you are using Spring-test v2.5 and Junit 4.7, it looks like spring-test v2.5 might only support Junit v4.4.

Try to downgrade to JUnit 4.4 or upgrade to spring-test v2.5.6 and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Downgrading to Junit 4.4 while using Spring 2.5.6 fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks heaps, I've been trying to solve this issue for a couple of hours now.

Answer (score 5):

I have to keep Spring v2.5, downgrading to JUnit 4.4 resolves the problem.

Moreover, you'll see original cause hidden by Assume$AssumptionViolatedException ;)

FYI, Moving to latest spring-test 2.5.6 won't change anything.

Linked SO : [Junit4 + Spring 2.5 : Asserts throw "NoClassDefFoundError"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693115/junit4-spring-2-5-asserts-throw-noclassdeffounderror)

Answer (score 1):

I found that spring-test 2.5.x expects the org.junit.Assume to contain AssumptionViolatedException, but in junit 4.10 it has been moved to the org.junit.internal package. The tests will stop running (not fail) with ClassNotFoundException.

My workaround was to add my own JUnit Assume copy based on 4.10 and add the AssumptionViolatedException (from internal). This local copy must be added to the classpath first is your IDE and build tool.

```
public class Assume {

    /*
     * Ported this from JUnit 4.4 to satisfy spring-test
     */
    public static class AssumptionViolatedException extends org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public AssumptionViolatedException(Object value, Matcher<?> matcher) {
            super(value, matcher);
        }
    }
    // rest of Assume from JUint 4.10 ....
}
```

The disadvantage is that this class will obviously get stale quickly and future users of the code may not know it exists; it's a future failure waiting to happen.

Also it might not get loaded first. To mitigate this I added tests that check the Assume is loaded first and warn if not:

```
import java.net.URL;

public class JUnitSpringTestAssumeOverrideCompatibilityChecker {
    public static void checkAssumeOverridden() {
        URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("org/junit/Assume.class");

        if (!"file".equals(url.getProtocol())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Expect local override (1st on classpath) of JUnit 4.10 Assume for spring-test 2.5 compatibility");
        }
    }
}
```