# Intellj reports assertion failure though all tests are passed

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm new to Java and Junit testing. But why would this occur?  Been fighting with this for awhile.
[image]

Sorry image is so small. But it was the only way to capture both sides.

Comment: The logs do not read AssertionError. Could you share the test definition which you pointing to. Chances are you might be throwing an Exception from the test itself or catching it by your own. Infact, this could be desired behaviour as well.

Comment: Just in case somebody other than the moderators will find this interesting/useful... my issue  was that I had NOT added the "throw Exception" to the method!  Coming from .Net this syntax is very foreign to me.. Hence the exception was thrown, and rather than being defined as a possible result (especially in a test), it was treated like an exception in the actual code base.

Something so basic to Java, it's not mentioned in the Test documentation, or  as a possible issue that could be occurring in tests... 

My only question - if a test method aborts - why is it not treated as a failure?

Comment: moderators - if this question is off-topic, then a suggestion as to where to put it would be more helpful. If you are not part of the solution, you are part of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You're running your tests with the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`, but the correct version of JUnit4 is not in your classpath.

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497857/trying-to-run-junit-test-on-service-level-of-spring-webflow-project-assumeassu

Comment: teppic - So this wasn't the answer, but it at least started me on what could be wrong. Thanks for the help! +1